# What's the preferred way to distribute self written Unity Lenses?

Tags: unity, application-development, lenses

With gnome-shell there is https://extensions.gnome.org where a developer could easily submit and distribute an self written gnome-shell extension.

What's the preferred way with a self written Unity Lens? Creating an PPA for a Lens seems more work than uploading the files to a website.
On the other hand nobody could find my self written Lens when I'm only create an PPA?!

Answer (score 3):

[Publishing your Lens in the Software Centre](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/) would be the best bet. There isn't a dedicated section for Lenses at this time, but that seems like the sort of things that would change in the future.